# Does order of Hibernate queries affect results?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, session

*I can't reproduce this issue now. Will post if I could repeat.*

There are two entities: Teacher & Student

The codes are like:

```
Student s1 = (Student)session.get(Student.class, id);
Teacher t1 = (Teacher)session.get(Teacher.class, id1);
String name = t1.getName(); //returned null
```

s1 is returned properly. t1 is returned, however, all fields are null.

Then, I tried to change the order of two queries:

```
Teacher t1 = (Teacher)session.get(Teacher.class, id1);
Student s1 = (Student)session.get(Student.class, id);
String name = t1.getName(); //returned t1's name
```

In this case, both t1 and s1 are returned properly.

Does the order affect the Hibernate query results?

Comment: The order of the queries should not have any effect to the result.

Comment: I suppose that `Student` have lazy reference to `Teacher`. Looks like you getting proxy instead of real object. How you noticed that fields are null? You saw it in debugger? If so try to do `t1.getSomething()` and look again.

Comment: @talex, t1.getSomething() also returns null. So, I guess it isn't a proxy/real object issue

Comment: It shouldn't, but it may affect performance to **get to the result**.